# update in a nested array using C# Driver in MongoDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Here is my exact schema:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d45"),
"Name" : "Agent name",
"City" : "XXXX",
"BranchOffice" : [{

    "_id" : ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d46"),
    "Name" : "Branch name",
    "City" : "XXXX",
    "SubBranch" : [{

        "_id" : ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d47"),
        "Name" : "Sub-Branch Name",
        "City" : "XXXX"
        "Users" : [{

            "_id" : ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d48"),
            "Name" : "User",
            "City" : "XXXX"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

Its Inserted successfully in c#. insert code was below  but update condition is failed .

I want to update field 3 level and 4 level of array using SubBranch and users

***Insert code***

```
IMongoQuery query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d45)),

Query.EQ("BranchOffice._id", new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d46)));

Agent agent = dc.Collection.FindOne(query);

BsonDocument branchOffice = agent.BranchOffice.Find(objId => objId._id ==    new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d46)).ToBsonDocument();
```

subBranch I had get List object convert to BsonDocument

Files: name,city,_Id, and users for array

```
BsonDocument subBranchOffice = **subBranch.ToBsonDocument()**;

if (branchOffice.Contains("SubBranch"))
{
    if (branchOffice["SubBranch"].IsBsonNull)
    {
        branchOffice["SubBranch"] = new BsonArray().Add(BsonValue.Create(subBranchOffice));
    }
    else
    {                                     
        branchOffice["SubBranch"].AsBsonArray.Add(BsonValue.Create(subBranchOffice));
    }

    var update = Update.Set("BranchOffice.$.SubBranch",branchOffice["SubBranch"]); 
    SafeModeResult s = dc.Collection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert,SafeMode.True);
}
```

**Here SafemodeResult is UpdateExisting = true**

**Here Inserted Option is successfully**

next I try to update in else Statement. I am not get it answer

***Update code***

```
else
{
    var queryEdit = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d45)), 

    Query.EQ("BranchOffice._id", new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d46)),
    Query.EQ("SubBranchlist._id", new ObjectId(4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d47)));

    **//Index value 1 or 2 or 3**

    var update = Update.Set("BranchOffice.$.SubBranch."index value".Name", "sname").

    Set("BranchOffice.$.SubBranch."index value".city", "yyyyy" ?? string.Empty);
    SafeModeResult s = dc.Collection.Update(queryEdit, update, UpdateFlags.None,SafeMode.True);
}
```

**Here SafemodeResult is UpdateExisting = False**

**Here updated Option is fail**

Please explain how to solve this probelm and how to update field 2 and 3 level of array

Please show any Example

Comment: Similar issue for the latest driver and mongoDb: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62491722/mongo-error-when-trying-to-update-nested-arrays-no-array-filter-found-for-ident/62493967#62493967

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot there, but it looks like at least part of your problem is that you've spelled BranchOffice differently between the data and the query you are using to update, also you've missed the hierarchy in SubBranch, so your queryEdit in the last code sample won't match the document. This will;

```
db.so.find({
    _id: ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d45"),
    "BrancheOffice._id": ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d46"),
    "BrancheOffice.SubBranch._id": ObjectId("4fb4fd04b748611ca8da0d47"),
}).toArray()
```

Comment: This Section is very helpful for me. I am using hierarchy in yours method "BrancheOffice.SubBranch._id"

Comment: Cool. What else do you need to complete your answer?

Comment: Thanks for help me. All things was completed in my application and also thanks for asking me. If I have any doubt means, I will ask you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you mind ticking my answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem? many thanks.